# Maven artifact issue with stardog and sesame dependencies

Tags: maven, rdf, jena, sesame, stardog

I have a program, developed in a maven project through Eclipse, that provides an ETL service which ingests data, generates turtle format RDF using the Jena API, and loads it into a triple store which requires data sent to it using the Sesame API. As such, I need to convert the statements created by the ETL service from Jena to Sesame.

I want to use the [following class](http://docs.stardog.com/java/snarl/com/complexible/stardog/jena/JenaSesameUtils.html) from Stardog, as it does precisely what I need to do. I tried to add the following  dependencies to my pom.xml to resolve the issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.complexible.stardog.protocols.http</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
        <version>${stardog.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Depends on this as if it were a jar artifact, when it is a pom -->
                <artifactId>sesame</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.complexible.stardog.reasoning.http</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
        <version>${stardog.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Depends on this as if it were a jar artifact, when it is a pom -->
                <artifactId>sesame</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.complexible.stardog</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>${stardog.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Depends on this as if it were a jar artifact, when it is a pom -->
                <artifactId>sesame</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>license</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.clarkparsia</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>erg</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.complexible.erg</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

but I get the following errors:

Missing artifact com.complexible.stardog:shared:jar 2.2.2

Missing artifact org.openrdf.sesame:sesame:jar:2.7.12

Missing artifact com.complexible.stardog:api:jar.2.2.2

I also get errors on the opening Dependency tag for the above dependencies saying that the dependency contained within it is also missing.

Note: stardog.version = 2.2.2 and sesame.version = 2.7.12.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know how to help you with the maven dependency problem - this looks very specific to Stardog. If you don't get an answer here you might try asking about this on their support mailinglist instead.

However, I can offer an alternative solution: instead of using a convertor class, you just serialize the Jena objects back to N-Triples or Turtle, and then parse them using Sesame's Rio parser - which will of course create Sesame API objects.

I'm not too familiar with the Jena API but I'm sure there is a way you can write a model to, say, an `OutputStream` in Turtle format. Once you have that `OutputStream`, you can simply do something like this:

```java
// in case of very large files, use something more efficient, like a   
// PipedOutputStream, or first write back to disk
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()); 

// parse the data using Sesame Rio, which provides a Sesame Model     
// object. You can of course also immediately write the  
// data to the store instead of first creating a Model.
org.openrdf.model.Model model = Rio.parse(in, "", RDFFormat.TURTLE);
```

Comment: That worked. As a note for anyone else that tries to do this, you need to instantiate your RDFWriter with the same format you plan to parse with. For the example above, you need to instantiate it as a TURTLE.